# Query to find field duplicate between 9 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 9 tables each with value like

```
Level_1_tab

Code  Name

ae1   hdgdgd
ae2   dhdh


level_2_tab

code Name
2     jfjfjf
3      fkfjfjf
```

similarly `level_3_tab , level_4_tab, level_5` table so on and so forth till level_9_tab.

I am inserting the code column into a new table and checking for duplicates.

```
   SELECT
        code, name, COUNT(*)
    FROM
        new_table
    GROUP BY
        code, name
    HAVING 
        COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Can i write a query and compare the code column of these 9 tables and check for duplicates ? that all the rows with duplicate code values should be retrieved

Comment: the way I would do it is create a temp table that is the union of all values from the various tables, and select the Codes from there that have a count > 1.  Then it is trivial to find the values in their parent tables.

Comment: While the `UNION ALL` suggestion by @mo2, below,  is right on. The fact that you have to do a union for these tables suggests that maybe your schema is not great. Why not have these all in a single table with structure `Code | Name | Level` ?

Comment: @JNevill your suggestion for a new schema is good as their could be benefit, you never know what you inhert when doign ETL though!  Anyway, the UNION ALL is great to find the duplicates but the alsnwer from mo2 doesn' t actually return the duplicate records.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `union all` of the 9 tables and run your same query on that.

```
 select code, name, count(*) from 
   (select code, name from table 1 union all
    select code, name from table 2 union all
    select code, name from table 3 union all
    select code, name from table 4 union all
    .....)
 group by code, name
 having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: This won't return the actual duplicate rows it will just return which codes have duplicates

Comment: If just the two columns are needed then it doesn't matter.  Unless maybe OP needs to find out which tables have them.  Then you could manually add the table name to the union queries and then join back as you suggested.

Comment: Because his code will definitely return the duplicates already I guess I am reading that he then wants to return all of the records which are actually duplicates.  I guess it isn't totally clear though and between us I think we killed the answer by now :)

Answer (score 0):

Everyone's suggestion of union all is great to build your initial table to look for duplicates in.  But you say you already have a temp table with all of the values from the 9 tables which is perfect and another great way of doing it if your dataset isn't huge.

The only step your missing from your description to get the actually duplicate rows is to use your duplicate query above to re-query your temp table and return the rows you want.  A great way of doing this is through common table expressions which basically allows you to build a query on top of your other query without another temp table.  So use a cte and join back to your temp table.

```
;WITH CommonTableExpression AS (
  SELECT
        code, name, COUNT(*)
    FROM
        new_table
    GROUP BY
        code, name
    HAVING 
        COUNT(*) > 1;
)

SELECT t.*
FROM
    new_table t
    INNER JOIN CommonTableExpression c
    ON t.code = c.code
```

AND t.name = c.name

If you want to do it to each of the 9 tables independently rather than to your temp table.  Place the duplicates into another temp table and join on it.

```
SELECT
    code, name, COUNT(*)
INTO #Duplicates
FROM
    new_table
GROUP BY
    code, name
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1

SELECT
   l.*
FROM
   leve_1_tab l
   INNER JOIN #Duplicates d
   ON l.Code = d.Code
AND l.name = d.name
```

Seeing everyone loves `union all` here is a way to do it with out temp tables and lots of `union all` s I wonder which would be a more optimized query though.

```
;WITH cteAllCodeValues AS (
    select code, name from table 1 union all
    select code, name from table 2 union all
    select code, name from table 3 union all
    select code, name from table 4 union all
    --.....)
)

, cteDuplicates AS (
    SELECT code, name, RecordCount = COUNT(*)
    FROM
       cteAllCodeValues
    GROUP BY
       code, name
)

SELECT c.*
FROM
    cteDuplicates d
    INNER JOIN cteAllCodeValues c
    ON d.code = c.code
    AND d.name = c.name
```

Comment: You could just join from the suggested UNION subquery without having to write a CTE, but... 6 of one, half a dozen of the other. If this were me stuck with this bad schema, I would add the tables name to the UNION as a third column so I could walk back to which tables the duplicates came from, which would be one more step on top of this.

Comment: @JNevill agreed with you on the schema and adding table names even for the temp table he already has adding it there would be good too.  As far as cte I perfer those over subqueries for read ability and I just don't want to type all of those union alls a second time :)